# VBA Get one or more links from web (from cells)

Tags: excel, vba

I need this for my job. Someone wrote us a macro. This macro contains a module that take links from cells and download the files. 
However. Problem is that it must be 2 rows or more that contain links. 
This is nonsense for me/us as we often just download one link/file = only 1 row.

So the code must be able to handle a single row and multiple rows.

I can code a bit HTML and PHP, but that's quite long time ago.

I understand that the error "Subscript out of range" (= ext = buf(UBound(buf)) ) 
is because of the array. Or the way the array is being handled. But that's it.

To be honest I have not enough time to learn VBA to a point to fix this. I also only have access to these files at work...and here at work...I have to work lol.

So, help would be highly appreciated.

```
Sub DownloadFilefromWeb()
    Dim strSavePath As String
    Dim URL As String, ext As String
    Dim buf, ret As Long
    Dim fi As String
    Dim lrow5 As Long
   Dim path As String

    Call Clear_All_Files_And_SubFolders_In_Folder
    lrow5 = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    Worksheets("Link").Range("G2:G" & lrow5).Formula = "=GetURL(E2)"

    j = 1
    For i = 2 To lrow5
        fi = Worksheets("Link").Range("A" & i).Value
        URL = Worksheets("Link").Range("G" & i).Value
        buf = Split(URL, ".")
        ext = buf(UBound(buf))
        'MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Path
        strSavePath = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\Backup\" & fi & "," & j & "." & ext
        ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, strSavePath, 0, 0)
        j = j + 1
       'If ret = 0 Then
       '     MsgBox "Download has been succeed!"
       'Else
       '     MsgBox "Error"
       'End If

    Next i
  MsgBox ("Download Completed")
End Sub
```

Edit:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without knowing/seeing the layout of the sheet.

I'll guess/assume that row 1 of the `Links` worksheet contains headers, and that the data itself (that you want to loop through) begins from row 2.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DownloadFilefromWeb()
    Dim strSavePath As String
    Dim URL As String
    Dim ret As Long
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim fileExtension As String

    Call Clear_All_Files_And_SubFolders_In_Folder

    With Worksheets("Link")
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("G2:G" & lastRow).Formula = "=GetURL(E2)"

        Dim fileCount As Long
        fileCount = 1

        Dim rowIndex As Long
        For rowIndex = 2 To lastRow
            Filename = .Range("A" & rowIndex).Value
            URL = .Range("G" & rowIndex).Value
            fileExtension = VBA.Strings.Mid$(URL, VBA.Strings.InStrRev(URL, ".", -1, vbBinaryCompare))

            strSavePath = .Parent.path & "\Backup\" & Filename & "," & fileCount & fileExtension
            ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, strSavePath, 0, 0) ' <- Don't seem to do anything with this value. Maybe include a MsgBox alert if it returns a non-zero value.

            fileCount = fileCount + 1
        Next rowIndex
    End With

    MsgBox ("Download Completed")
End Sub
```

Main difference is that `lastRow` is assigned working from the sheet's last row upward (previously it was downward from row 2, meaning it could never be only row 2 i.e. one row of data).

Comment: HI. Thank you.

I've edited my orignal post and added a screenshot on the layout

Comment: @Alex, from what I can see, my assumption/guess was correct. When you get a chance at work, try the code and see if it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
lrow5 = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
```

This gets the number of rows from the current workbook and worksheet. Then in the loop:

```
For i = 2 To lrow5
```

it starts at the second row. If you want it to start at the first row (and if there is only one row), then change his to:

```
For i = 1 To lrow5
```

---

Note: what I don't understand in this code is the line:

```
Worksheets("Link").Range("G2:G" & lrow5).Formula = "=GetURL(E2)"
```

It seems this sets *all* of the hyperlinks to the URL of cell E2, i.e. to the *same* URL.

The `GetURL` function is a custom function. See http://howtouseexcel.net/how-to-extract-a-url-from-a-hyperlink-on-excel

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick reply. I've added a screenshot on my original post.
What you suggested, I've tried already. But it gives me the same Error '9' Subscript out of range

The part you don't understand is, it takes the Link from that cell and copies it to E2 (E3, E4, E5 etc.) I am not sure why it does so. As said, I guess the guy who made this macro, just copy&pasted stuff together.

Comment: User chillin below got the solution. Thank you anyways :)